# Open vSwitch GRE over IPSec

Tags: networking, tunnel, bridge, ipsec, openvswitch

I am trying to estalbish an GRE over IPSec tunnel between my hosts. Regular IPSec works:

**Host 1:**

```
ovs-vsctl add-br mybr0
ifconfig mybr0 10.0.0.1/24 up
ovs-vsctl add-port mybr0 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=gre options:remote_ip=172.16.0.206
```

**Host 2**

```
ovs-vsctl add-br mybr0
ifconfig mybr0 10.0.0.2/24 up
ovs-vsctl add-port mybr0 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=gre options:remote_ip=172.16.0.204
```

With the above configuration, I can create a connection between hosts and can easily ping them. However, when I do the same procedure with ipsec as below, it does not work, not able to ping because it cannot find the host.

```
ovs-vsctl add-port mybr0 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=ipsec_gre options:remote_ip=172.16.0.206 options:psk=mustafa
```

IPSec daemon is installed on both hosts confirmed by running, `systemctl status openvswitch-ipsec.service`, what am I missing in this configuration?